# How to scan several drives for specific directories?

Tags: c#, file-io

I am not looking for specific files but rather specific directories to index all files in those directories.  I am aware of how to search for file types and names but not how to do that with directories for indexing.

Comment: Have you tried using [Directory.GetDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314(v=vs.110).aspx?)

Comment: Does "for indexing" mean you are trying to build your own index, or looking for a way to query the existing index built by "Windows Search"?  Be aware that the latter doesn't include the entire drive by default.

Comment: I have, however I do not know what the base directory will be to begin searching.  For example I am looking for a folder called myStuff that could be in drive C:, D:, E:, or F:.

Comment: Building my own index.  Once the files are indexed I will be transferring them to a server as an automatic backup and version monitoring system.

Comment: @Engineer13441 If you are searching multiple drives then call it once for each drive.

Comment: @juharr That would work great, but I do not know what the drives would be and it would be very slow and data intensive to scan each drive from A: to Z:

Comment: @Engineer13441 I think you can use [DriveInfo.GetDrives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this: (as taken from MS code examples)

```
public class StackBasedIteration
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Specify the starting folder on the command line, or in  
        // Visual Studio in the Project > Properties > Debug pane.
        TraverseTree(args[0]);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void TraverseTree(string root)
    {
        // Data structure to hold names of subfolders to be 
        // examined for files.
        Stack<string> dirs = new Stack<string>(20);

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(root))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        dirs.Push(root);

        while (dirs.Count > 0)
        {
            string currentDir = dirs.Pop();
            string[] subDirs;
            try
            {
                subDirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(currentDir);
            }
            // An UnauthorizedAccessException exception will be thrown if we do not have 
            // discovery permission on a folder or file. It may or may not be acceptable  
            // to ignore the exception and continue enumerating the remaining files and  
            // folders. It is also possible (but unlikely) that a DirectoryNotFound exception  
            // will be raised. This will happen if currentDir has been deleted by 
            // another application or thread after our call to Directory.Exists. The  
            // choice of which exceptions to catch depends entirely on the specific task  
            // you are intending to perform and also on how much you know with certainty  
            // about the systems on which this code will run. 
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {                    
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                continue;
            }
            catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                continue;
            }

            string[] files = null;
            try
            {
                files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(currentDir);
            }

            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                continue;
            }

            catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                continue;
            }
            // Perform the required action on each file here. 
            // Modify this block to perform your required task. 
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Perform whatever action is required in your scenario.
                    System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}", fi.Name, fi.Length, fi.CreationTime);
                }
                catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    // If file was deleted by a separate application 
                    //  or thread since the call to TraverseTree() 
                    // then just continue.
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    continue;
                }
            }

            // Push the subdirectories onto the stack for traversal. 
            // This could also be done before handing the files. 
            foreach (string str in subDirs)
                dirs.Push(str);
        }
    }
}
```

I would simply modify to only get the files once you are in the directory you want to be looking in.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the path of each logical drive to begin my search by adding `System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives();` and storing the resulting list then passing those strings into the answer by [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642891/charles)